# Why does Latex/Bibtex need three passes to clear up all warnings?

Tags: bibtex, compiling

As explained [by Andy Roberts](http://www.andy-roberts.net/writing/latex/bibliographies), if you need to compile a new document with bibtex citations, then you need to run latex three times, and bibtex once:

```
latex document
bibtex document
latex document
latex document
```

Why can't latex figure this out itself, and just do what it needs to do? What is it doing in the later runs that it can't do in the earlier runs?

Comment: I recommend **latexmk** ([Homepage](http://www.phys.psu.edu/~collins/latexmk/)/[CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/latexmk)), which does what you're demanding: It figures out what needs to be run how often all by itself. It works well with BibTeX and Biber, but might need some fine-tuning for other things, e.g. glossaries, about which you'll find questions on here. The author is also very responsive and actually answers questions here on tex.sx.

Comment: @doncherry: I actually use pdflatex, does latexmk output to pdf?

Comment: Yes, use it like this: `latexmk -pdf foo.tex`. There are many more options available, e.g. latexmk can automatically compile whenever you save the .tex file (that's the `-pvc` [preview continuously] option). Check out its manual, it's fairly comprehensible.

Comment: `latexmk` actually does run all the above command; so it is an answer to  _Why can't latex figure this out itself, and just do what it needs to do?_ but not to _What is it doing in the later runs that it can't do in the earlier runs?_

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The reason is as follows:

1. At the first `latex` run, all `\cite{...}` arguments are written in the file `document.aux`.
2. At the `bibtex` run, this information is taken by bibtex and the relevant entries are put into the `.bbl` file, sorted either alphabetically or by citation order (sometimes called "unsorted") and formatted according to the instructions provided by the bibliography style that's in use.
3. At the next run of `latex`, the `.bbl` file is included at the point the `\bibliography` instructions, and the correct labels for `\cite{...}` commands are written in `.aux` file.
4. Only at the last run, `latex` knows what the correct labels are and includes them in the document.

The reason why TeX and BibTeX have been made this way is that back then, the memories used to be small, and file systems were the only good ways to store files. But you cannot read and write the same file (well, you can, but it's more complicated), that's why you have to run `latex` twice after `bibtex`, as well as you have to run it twice where you cross-reference etc.

Some passes can be saved using `biblatex` instead of `bibtex`. Anyways, all references (and cross-references) stabilize during the document preparation since all of us compile our documents many times...

Comment: `biblatex` doesn't avoid the need of multiple pass processing.

Comment: I have always thought that it reduces at least one pass...

Comment: Yes, it may avoid one pass. But it's not so important to always do all passes: it's quite often only a waste of time. Cross references will stabilize during document preparation and it's not necessary that they are always correct. Just remember to run BibTeX (or Biber) when  citations are added.

Comment: That's what I meant. I hope I have put it in correctly now...

Comment: Ah, so the reason is historical (memory). You'd wonder why 'they' haven't updated latex to /not/ cater for memory limited systems anymore (at least not by default)...

Comment: @Rabarberski remember that (1) "they" are the active members here, (2) it is close-to-impossible to make LaTeX "move some information backwards", (3) it is not a big deal to try to find complicated solutions and (4) there're tools like `latexmk` or `arara` to ease you this.

Comment: Some BibTeX-related overview (includes a table explaining the four compilation steps): http://amath.colorado.edu/documentation/LaTeX/reference/faq/bibstyles.html

Comment: Is the process/explanation the same for pdflatex?

Comment: @DavidDoria Yes, it is. Remember that `pdf/ps/lua/xe/(dvi)-latex` differ only by the treatment of fonts and figures, and by the output format (and availability of `lua` in `lualatex`).

Comment: The amath.colorado.edu link has since broken, but [this was the latest working snapshot from the archive.org](http://web.archive.org/web/20130620150431/http://amath.colorado.edu/documentation/LaTeX/reference/faq/bibstyles.html).  Note: it doesn't add much if any more detail to the process than @tohecz's excellent answer.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of providing a bit more information about the output of the bibtex run. Hope you agree.

Comment: @Mico I want to upvote the answer now! :)

Comment: I've already upvoted the answer for you. -:)