# how to add citation to figure like Figure:.2.4[1]

Tags: captions

how to add citation to figure like Figure:.2.4[1]
Because I am adding `\cite{b1}` in caption it will print index.So where to add citation so it will add on figure.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2):

You can put citations in the caption. For example:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
    \begin{mdframed}[userdefinedwidth=.9\textwidth,align=center,]
        \myfloatalign
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{./gfx/myfigure.jpg}
    \end{mdframed}
     \caption[the title of the figure.]{The title of the figure \citep{author:2015}}
\end{figure}
```

The result from this example is:

```
Figure 2.1: the title of the figure (author, 2015)
```

or depending on your bib settings

```
Figure 2.1: the title of the figure [1]
```

Comment: offcourse you may have to run (pdf)latex multiple times to make sure the references/citations get rendered. See e.g., [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53235/why-does-latex-bibtex-need-three-passes-to-clear-up-all-warnings).