# Compilation of a Springer paper using svjour3 and BibTex for a TEX absolute beginner

Tags: bibtex, errors, compiling

this is the first time I have tried using the TEX code. I cannot compile my text. I use Windows 10, and the code below yields error messages that I transcribe in the console output. Can anybody be patient enough to help me?

```
\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}
\smartqed
\usepackage{latexsym}
\journalname{Synthesis}
\begin{document}
\title{Consciousness without puzzles: Pauen against Churchland, but why exactly?}
\author{C. Daniel Andrade}
\institute{C. Daniel Andrade \at
   Universidade Federal do Ceará, Brazil \\
   \email{andradecdaniel@ufc.br}      \\}
\date{Received: date / Accepted: date}
% The correct dates will be entered by the editor
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
Michael Pauen [...].
\keywords{Consciousness \and Churchland \and Pauen \and eliminativism \and levels \and aspects \and perspectives}\end{abstract}
\section{Introduction}
\label{sec:1}
\paragraph Pauen (\cite{pauen2015}) identifies in present-day [...] 
\paragraph In his words, \begin{quote}[c]rucial doubts [...] eliminative materialists
\footnote{Original in German: ``Prinzipielle Zweifeln an den Grundz\''\ugen unseres Menschenbildes, also daran, dass wir Bewusstsein haben, Selbstbewusstsein und Verantwortlichkeit, sind auch in der neueren Philosophiegeschichte nur selten ernsthaft vertreten worden; zu den wenigen Ausnahmen z\''\ahlen die Materialisten des 19. Jahrhunderts wie beispielsweise Carl Vogt oder die Eliminative Materialisten unserer Tage.''}\end{quote} (Pauen \cite{pauen2015}, p. 28).   %line 17

 [...]

\bibliographystyle{spr-chicago}
\bibliography{article-Synthesis-references}
\nocite{*}
\end{document}
```

---

Console output:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (MiKTeX 2.9)
entering extended mode
(C:/Users/Daniel/Dropbox/myArticle---Synthesis-Latex/myArticle-Synthesis.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ar
abic, armenian, assamese, basque, bengali, bokmal, bulgarian, catalan, coptic, 
croatian, czech, danish, dutch, esperanto, estonian, farsi, finnish, french, ga
lician, german, german-x-2013-05-26, greek, gujarati, hindi, hungarian, iceland
ic, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, kannada, kurmanji, latin, latvian,
 lithuanian, malayalam, marathi, mongolian, mongolianlmc, monogreek, ngerman, n
german-x-2013-05-26, nynorsk, oriya, panjabi, pinyin, polish, portuguese, roman
ian, russian, sanskrit, serbian, slovak, slovenian, spanish, swedish, swissgerm
an, tamil, telugu, turkish, turkmen, ukenglish, ukrainian, uppersorbian, usengl
ishmax, welsh, loaded.
(C:\Users\Daniel\Dropbox\myArticle---Synthesis-Latex\svjour3.cls
Document Class: svjour3 2007/05/08 v3.2 
LaTeX document class for Springer journals
(C:\Users\Daniel\Dropbox\myArticle---Synthesis-Latex\svglov3.clo
SVJour Class option: svglov3.clo for standardised journals
)) ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\latexsym.sty")
(C:\Users\Daniel\Dropbox\myArticle---Synthesis-Latex\myArticle-Synthesis.aux)

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmr/bx/n' in size <13> not available
(Font)              size <12> substituted on input line 13.

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\ulasy.fd")

LaTeX Warning: Citation `pauen2015' on page 1 undefined on input line 17.

[1{C:/ProgramData/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}]
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...elle Zweifeln an den Grundz\''\ugen 
                                                  unseres Menschenbildes, al...
l.17 ...Eliminative Materialisten unserer Tage.''}
                                                  \end{quote} (Pauen \cite{p...

?
```

Comment: Welcome,  we all have been absolute beginners once. A good step to being more than just a beginner is reading [LaTeX for complete novices](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/index.html). It will tell you how you get umlauts and other diacritics in your document.  It will also tell you what the command `\paragraph` is supposed to be doing and how you can get a bibliography.

Comment: There is a big difference between `\''` (two single apostrophe marks) and `\"` (a single double apostrophe mark). Also, `\ugen` is undefined by default.  What word are you trying to write? Grundzügen? i.e.,  Grundz\"ugen?

Comment: Johannes_/B, thank your for the tip.

Comment: jon, yes, I meant Grundzügen. I tried to follow instructions on a 171-page introduction to Latex. Since I was told to replace each closing double quote sign with two plain-text apostrophes, I might have mixed it up with the codes for umlauts.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, I noticed that you used `\''\u` to try to write the ü-umlaut. The shortcut for the three German umlauts and the sz ligature actually are:

- `\"a` for ä, `\"A` for Ä
- `\"o` for ö, `\"O` for Ö
- `\"u` for ü, `\"U` for Ü
- `\ss{}` for ß

What is way easier than typing those shortcuts and leads to a cleaner source, though, is saving your files with UTF-8 encoding and using the `inputenc` package with the `utf8` option as well as `fontenc` like so:

```
\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\smartqed
\usepackage{latexsym}
…
```

---

Next, the warning for undefined citation you get won't stop the document from compiling but will lead to problems with referencing in your pdf—**(?)** will show up in the text whenever there's a broken reference.
The warning tells you that you tried to reference `pauen2015` but that it couldn't be found in your bibliography. Therefore, you should add an item with that reference to your `article-Synthesis-references.bib` file or check whether the source you intended to cite actually has a different key that you need to use for referencing.

As *cfr* pointed out in the comments, it might also be possible that you simply didn't run BibTeX as LaTeX requires multiple runs to get all the references right. Since I've been using [`latexmk`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/latexmk/?lang=en) for quite some time now, I forgot about that completely …
A chain of commands you have to execute can be found in the following question at [»Why does Latex/Bibtex need three passes to clear up all warnings?« @ TeX.Sx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53235/why-does-latex-bibtex-need-three-passes-to-clear-up-all-warnings) as well as an explanation why that is even necessary, in the answers.

And also, as Johannes_B pointed out, you might want to read some further introductions to LaTeX. I personally started with the [Not so short introduction to LaTeX](https://tobi.oetiker.ch/lshort/lshort.pdf), but since you said that you read a documentation with 171 pages, I guess that's where you started.
I have no experience with [LaTeX for Complete Novices](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/index.html), but having had a quick glimpse, I think it could be a good starting point.
Unfortunately, in the beginning the LaTeX way sometimes seems harder than it needs to be—and in some ways probably even is—but with some learning, you can get some great results with it.

---

You don't have to—and shouldn't—start every paragraph with `\paragraph`. LaTeX automatically deems every coherent text block as a paragraph.
A new paragraph is started as soon as a completely blank line is set in between like so:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.

At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
```

Here, the two paragraphs that you can see as text blocks will be deemed as text blocks by LaTeX.
Cases where you *would* use `\paragraph` for is when you want to have a paragraph headline/title. It depends on the style, though, how they are presented.

Often, this:

```
\paragraph{Heading} This is my document text.
```

would lead to something like this:

> **Heading** This is my document text.

---

The German quote sounds odd to me. In the beginning it should be »Prinzipielles Zweifeln« and in the end, I guess, »oder die eliminativen Materialisten unserer Tage«.

---

So all in all, the following LaTeX source sums up what I wrote above. Please make sure to check that my corrections to the German sentence are indeed what your original source says.

I didn't know whether you are allowed to use other packages than the ones you already did use, so I went for the first option I wrote about above—writing umlauts with the \" shorthands.

```
\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}
\smartqed
\usepackage{latexsym}
\journalname{Synthesis}
\begin{document}
\title{Consciousness without puzzles: Pauen against Churchland, but why exactly?}
\author{C. Daniel Andrade}
\institute{C. Daniel Andrade \at
   Universidade Federal do Ceará, Brazil \\
   \email{andradecdaniel@ufc.br}      \\}
\date{Received: date / Accepted: date}
% The correct dates will be entered by the editor
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
Michael Pauen [...].
\keywords{Consciousness \and Churchland \and Pauen \and eliminativism \and levels \and aspects \and perspectives}\end{abstract}
\section{Introduction}
\label{sec:1}
Pauen (\cite{pauen2015}) identifies in present-day [...]
In his words, \begin{quote}[c]rucial doubts [...] eliminative materialists
\footnote{Original in German: ``Prinzipielles Zweifeln an den Grundz\"ugen unseres Menschenbildes, also daran, dass wir Bewusstsein haben, Selbstbewusstsein und Verantwortlichkeit, sind auch in der neueren Philosophiegeschichte nur selten ernsthaft vertreten worden; zu den wenigen Ausnahmen z\"ahlen die Materialisten des 19. Jahrhunderts wie beispielsweise Carl Vogt oder die eliminativen Materialisten unserer Tage.''}\end{quote} (Pauen \cite{pauen2015}, p. 28).   %line 17

 [...]

\bibliographystyle{spr-chicago}
\bibliography{article-Synthesis-references}
\nocite{*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is a nice summary (+1), though you should really acknowledge points made earlier in comments by other people. However, the most likely cause for the undefined reference is probably failure to run BibTeX. At the very least, you should mention this possibility.

Comment: @cfr You're right. I've been using `latexmk` for quite a while and totally forgot about the chain of command execution … I added some further detail to the paragraph about BibTeX.

Comment: Great! Of course, their setup probably isn't *broken*. They probably just need to run BibTeX ;).

Comment: Dear PattaFeuFeu, thank you so much for taking your time to write such a careful, instructive, clear answer! I look forward to have some time to put it all in practice.

Comment: I still didn't edit my code. One thing, though, that I can already say is about the reference. The key is exactly `pauen2015` both in the citations and in the BibTex file (article-Synthesis-references.bib).

Comment: Then please have a look at [this answer about BibTeX for Beginners](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13513/21625) here on TeX.Stackexchange. If that doesn’t help, please edit your question or we can go to a chatroom and try to solve your problem. :)