# References and citation call-outs are not printed

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, citing, natbib

I am writing an article. MWE is given below.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,times,12pt,ifthen]{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{nomencl}
%\makeindex
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[top= 2.00cm,bottom = 2.00cm,left= 2.00cm,right= 2.00cm]{geometry}
\makeatletter % these following 3 command will print reference without box
\renewcommand*{\@biblabel}[1]{\hfill#1.}
\makeatother
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage[acronym,nonumberlist]{glossaries} % prints glossary without page number at end
\usepackage{longtable} %spans table in two pages
\usepackage{subfigure} %gives subfigures
\usepackage{array} % justify table content
\usepackage{booktabs} % will center justified table
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\usepackage{color} % will print colour text
\bibliographystyle{agsm}
\RequirePackage{ifthen}
\renewcommand{\nomgroup}[1]{%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{G}}{\item[\textbf{Greek Symbols}]}{
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{S}}{\item[\textbf{Subscripts}]}{}}}
\makenomenclature
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
Comparing results in \citep{Shigley2011} with \citet{Duffy2010} and \cite{Carslaw1959}.

\makenomenclature
\printnomenclature
\printglossaries
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\bibliography{CoalCombustion.bib}
\end{document}
```

Bibtex file CoalCombustion.bib is

```
@book{Carslaw1959,
  title={Heat in solids},
  author={Carslaw, HS and Jaeger, JC},
  volume={19591},
  year={1959},
  publisher={Clarendon Press, Oxford}
}

@book{Duffy2010,
  title={Transform methods for solving partial differential equations},
  author={Duffy, Dean G},
  year={2010},
  publisher={CRC press}
}

@book{Shigley2011,
  title={Shigley's mechanical engineering design},
  author={Shigley, Joseph Edward},
  year={2011},
  publisher={Tata McGraw-Hill Education}
}
```

Output is
[image]

Why citations are not printed in text and reference?

Comment: Have you run `pdflatex` → `bibtex` → `pdflatex` → `pdflatex`? See [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53235/30280) for more information about this compilation cycle.

Comment: You have two separate `\bibliographystyle` instructions. Which style do you wish to load: `agsm` or `unsrtnat`?

Comment: Off-topic: The `subfigure` package is deprecated. Don't use it. Instead, use a package such as [subfig](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/subfig/).

Answer (score 2):

Some suggestions/observations:

- Change `\bibliography{CoalCombustion.bib}` to `\bibliography{CoalCombustion}`, i.e., omit the `.bib` extension.
- Choose one, and only one, bibliography style -- `agsm` or `unsrtnat`, *but not both*. If you choose the `agsm` style, load the `har2nat` package for maximal compatibility with packages such as `hyperref`.
- Be sure to run LaTeX, then BibTeX, and then LaTeX *twice more* to generate the citation call-outs expected from `\cite`, `\citep`, and `\citet`.

Comment: Your suggestion #2 worked for me and I retained unsrtnat style. I am facing two problems.
1. In article, citation comes with [] bracket but I want () bracket.
2. Reference comes in the order of its first cited in paper. I want it in alphabetical order.

I am compiling pdflatex ->bibtex -> pdflatex (twice).

Comment: @DharmeshkumarPatadiya - (i) Add the option `round` when loading `natbib`, i.e., type `\usepackage[authoryear,round]{natbib}`. (ii) The `unsrtnat` bibliography, as its name indicates, doesn't perform alphabetical sorting; use the `plainnat` style if you want the entries be sorted. After changing the bibliography style, be sure to run LaTeX, then BibTeX, and then LaTeX twice more to fully propagate the change.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am getting round parenthesis but citations are not sorted out in alphabetical order after using \bibliographystyle{plainnat} style.

Comment: @DharmeshkumarPatadiya - Three questions: (i) You have *only one* `\bibliographystyle` instruction, and the argument of that instruction is `plainnat`, right? (ii) After changing the argument of the one-and-only `\bibliographystyle` instruction, did you rerun LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more? (iii) Are you getting any error and/or warning messages related to the bibliography style in the `.log` and `.blg` files?

Comment: Answer to your questions (i)Yes, I have only one bibliography style with plainnat as argument (ii)Yes. I run it as you suggested using terminal pdflatex, bibtex, pdflatex (twice). (iii)No, I am not getting any error message in .blg and .log file.

One important observation it sort out with last name and middle name at beginning but not with first name. For example it sorts

HS Carslaw and JC Jaegar.....
Dean G Duffy....
Joseph Edward Shigley.....

While I want it like below
Carslaw, H. S. & Jaegar J. C, .....
Duffy, Dean. G.,....
Shigley, Joseph Edward,....

Comment: @DharmeshkumarPatadiya - Please post a *new* question, asking which bibliography style might be providing the formatting you need.