# OCG-Package: Not hiding link when printing document

Tags: hyperref, ocg, ocg-p

In my .tex file I added a hyperref link in my footer, which takes you back to the Table of contents. I want this link to disappear when I let the user print my document. I thought the OCG-P package would be my ideal solution for this, but I do not get the link to disappear when printing. Does anybody have an idea on how to fix this? I have provided an MWE below. Thanks in advance!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{datapie}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{ocg-p,hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Summary}

\patchcmd\tableofcontents{\contentsname}{\hypertarget{TOC}{\contentsname}}{}{\failed}

\begin{ocg}[printocg=never]{Footer2}{id1}{0}
\lfoot{\hyperlink{TOC}{$\leftarrow$ Summary}}
\end{ocg}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
    \newpage
    \tableofcontents
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \newpage
\end{titlepage}

\section{SECTION 1}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ocg` environment must be part of the footer definition. Put it inside the `\lfoot{...}` argument:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{datapie}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{ocgx2,hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Summary}

\patchcmd\tableofcontents{\contentsname}{\hypertarget{TOC}{\contentsname}}{}{\failed}

\lfoot{\begin{ocg}[printocg=never]{Footer2}{id1}{1}%
\hyperlink{TOC}{$\leftarrow$ Summary}%
\end{ocg}}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
    \newpage
    \tableofcontents
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \newpage
\end{titlepage}

\section{SECTION 1}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is still not working in my case. Could it have something to do with the pdf viewer I'm using? It is Document Viewer by Linux.

Comment: @RaphaelSpaans : Yes, this depends on the viewer. To my knowledge, only Acrobat Reader, Foxit (Windows) and the built-in PDF viewers of Firefox and Chrome support the OCG settings for printing.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem and the solution was that I needed to [run `pdflatex` twice](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53235/why-does-latex-bibtex-need-three-passes-to-clear-up-all-warnings).  It was only after the second run that the output PDF had the areas hidden correctly when printing.

Comment: This won't help with the document source as given in the question. As long as the `ocg` environment is not moved into the footer definition, the OCG-related PDF code won't make it into the PDF output.

Comment: True.  My answer was more because this question comes up first on Google, so it was more to help out others experiencing the same problem, but with a different underlying cause.